# npm run build - Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found

Tags: npm, webpack

I am trying to build a project for the first time and I am getting an error message.

```
Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.

Hash: 83fdf40d8aadb2841816
Version: webpack 4.18.0
Time: 180ms
Built at: 09/11/2018 4:55:53 AM

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/home/baudhi/website'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! website@15.19.1 build: `webpack --mode production`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the website@15.19.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/baudhi/.npm/_logs/2018-09-11T11_55_53_650Z-debug.log
```

The ebook I am reading has asked me to type 'npm run build' but it is not working. any help pls.

My package.json file looks like the following:

```
{  
  "name": "website",  
  "version": "15.19.1",  
  "description": "just practice",  
  "main": "main.js",  
  "scripts": {  
    "develop": "webpack --mode development --watch",  
    "build": "webpack --mode production"  
  },  
  "author": "pebaudhi",  
  "license": "ISC",  
  "devDependencies": {  
    "webpack": "^4.18.0",  
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"  
  },  
  "dependencies": {  
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"  
  }  
}
```

And my directory structure is:

```
/usr/baudhi/website/.babelrc  
/usr/baudhi/website/package.json  
/usr/baudhi/website/jquery-3.3.1.js  
/usr/baudhi/website/src/main.js  
/usr/baudhi/website/dist/main.js
```

node -v
v10.7.0

Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: What is your project folder structure?

Comment: How can we help you if you don't provide the relevant information? What does your package.json look like? How does your project structure look like? I'm afraid my crystal ball is under maintenance....

Comment: It looks like you are missing a webpack configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Webpack 4 the configuration has been defaulted. Hence, you don't need to provide a `webpack.config.json` file but you're project needs to follow the default config.

The default entry point in Webpack 4 is `./src/index.js`. So either rename `./src/main.js` or create `webpack.config.js` file with the following minimum.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js'
};
```